# no parameterless constructor defined for this object in C# using Sqlite-net ExecuteQuery method

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I am working with C# application using Sqlite-net. My query should return a single column value, but when i run the query i get the exception. My code is:

```
foreach(var group in groups)
{   
    var groupNameCmd = EdgeDatabase._connection.CreateCommand(@"SELECT Name from tblGroup WHERE Id = " + group.Id);
    List<string> groupName = groupNameCmd.ExecuteQuery<string>();
}
```

On the "ExecuteQuery" i get the exception "no parameterless constructor defined for this object".

Comment: if you are using .net core 2.0 check  your package refrence, generally this error come , if your package refrence and sdk installed version are not matching.

Comment: Maybe you can't use `string` as the target Type. Have you tried making a class with a string type property named `Name` and using that Type in place of `<string>`?

Comment: Exactly, cannot use "string", but unable to find the reason and the solution. @Crowcoder

Comment: It's because there is no parameterless constructor on String. Tools like this use reflection and it has nothing to use as a constructor argument. I mentioned a solution, use another Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the current answer of akg179 was downvotet, i write down my answer because I was just running into the same issue.

You cannot return a type which is missing a parameterless constructur (like string). Even a projection isn't possible in this case (using LINQ).

To only select a specific column (or multiple columns) you still have to use the right type in your method call (using the generic type):

```
foreach(var group in groups)
{   
    var groupNameCmd = EdgeDatabase._connection.CreateCommand(@"SELECT Name from tblGroup WHERE Id = " + group.Id);
    List<YourTblGroupType> groupName = groupNameCmd.ExecuteQuery<YourTblGroupType>();
}
```

You'll now get a list of *YourTblGroupType* but only the *Name* property will be set.

And if you really only wanna have the list of strings you can still use the following lambda expression afterwards:

```
List<string> names = groupName.Select(p => p.Name).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I inadvertently set the access modifier of the parameterless constructor of my object to internal rather than public.  Because the function creating the instance was from an external assembly, the constructor was not visible to it.  Changing the access modifier to public would resolve it.  In my situation I was able to use the object returned from the external assembly and use the constructor with parameters to create the object instance.

Answer (score -1):

You have used `group.Id` while creating your SQL command. This `group` should be an instance of a class.

Check if there is a parameter less constructor present in the class of which `group` is an instance of. If not, try adding a parameter less constructor to that class.

Comment: group ?? @akg179

Comment: I am getting this exception on second line @akg179

Comment: No, i am running this query in a loop, original code has been updated

Comment: saw ur updated code, still the `group` variable contains an instance of some class. `groups` is the collection of such instances. What is the datatype of `groups`?

Comment: var groups = EdgeDatabase._connection.Table<tblGroup>().ToList();
This is groups

Comment: So u need to check if `tblGroup` class has a parameter less constructor.